# API input model Validation using database table values in .net5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

Is there any way to validate input model values using data stored in db in .net5 without EF.

```
public class Search
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to check if the CurrentStatus value is matching with the values present in database table Stautues if not then throw validation error **Invalid Status**

Comment: Do you need to validate it on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Remote Validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#remote-attribute) - Here is an example

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult VerifyStatuc(string currentStatus)
{
    if (!_statusService.VerifyStatus(currentStatus))
    {
        return Json($"Invalid Status");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

And there is no dependency on EF Core - the `VerifyStatus` method can be implemented based on your requirements.